# Type or Namespace "Dapper" could not be found: in Hangfire Source code in Visual Studios?

Tags: nuget, hangfire

I've imported the Hangfire Source code from Github into my existing VS 2013 solution. When I attempted to build all projects within my solution, I get several errors:

```
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'Dapper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Jerry_Dev\Documents\GitHub\Hangfire\src\Hangfire.SqlServer\SqlServerDistributedLock.cs 20  7   Hangfire.SqlServer
```

In Package Manager, when I do: "Install-Package Dapper", it says

```
'Dapper 1.38' already installed.
Hangfire.SqlServer already has a reference to 'Dapper 1.38'.
```

I see `Dapper dot net` installed in my `Manage Nuget Packages` Window in my `Hangfire.SqlServer` project

Answer (score 1):

We don't store the `packages` folder under source control to reduce the source code size. Hangfire uses [Automatic Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore#Automatic_Package_Restore_in_Visual_Studio) in Visual Studio instead of obsolete MSBuild-integrated package restore. The Automatic Restore downloads missing packages automatically on each build, but it works only with NuGet ≥ 2.7, so you have the following options:

**Update NuGet to the latest version**

Please see the [official docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget#Updating_NuGet_in_Visual_Studio).

**Run the build script**

Go to the root Hangfire directory and run the `build.bat` file. It will automatically restore all the missing packages.